# Welcher Numerus muss im Passiv von »auf die Themen zurückgreifen« stehen?

Tags: grammatical-number, passive

Nach langem Überlegen kann ich leider immer noch nicht sagen, welcher der beiden folgenden Sätze korrekt ist.

Heißt es:

- > … die Themen, auf die später zurückgegriffen werden kann.
- > … auf die Themen kann später zurückgegriffen werden.

oder

- > … die Themen, auf die später zurückgegriffen werden können.
- > … auf die Themen können später zurückgegriffen werden.
- > die Themen können später beschrieben werden (richtig)

Ich bevorzuge die Variante mit *kann*, bin mir aber nicht sicher und weiß auch nicht wieso.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Im Aktiv lautet der Satz:

> (Jemand) kann auf die Themen zurückgreifen.
>
> Die Themen, auf die (jemand) später zurückgreifen kann.

Bei der Bildung des Passivs stellt sich die Frage, was im ursprünglichen Satz Subjekt und was Akkusativobjekt ist, diese beiden vertauschen ihre Rollen. Subjekt ist klar, das *jemand.* Ein Akkusativobjekt existiert nicht; die Themen sind ein Präpositionalobjekt (»*auf* die Themen«).

Präpositionalobjekt bleibt aber Präpositionalobjekt, auch wenn es im Akkusativ steht. Weil es kein Akkusativobjekt gibt, erhalten wir einen subjektlosen Passivsatz. Und wenn kein Subjekt existiert, fallen wir auf die 3. Person Singular zurück. Also:

> Es wird auf die Themen zurückgegriffen.
>
> Auf die Themen *kann* zurückgegriffen werden.
>
> Die Themen, *auf* die später zurückgegriffen werden *kann*.